# react-native calling function from different class --> redux mapDispatchToProps not working in called function

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

I call a function named `_listenToDB` , which resides in class `App`, but I call it FROM class `Search`.  Code for **calling** class `Search` is below:

```
import {app} from '../../App';
```

---

```
app._listenToDB();
```

Code for **called** class `App` is below:

```
import {_actAddUser} from './src/store/actions/actUsers';
```

---

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  _actAddUser: (snapshot) => {dispatch(_actAddUser(snapshot));},
  },
});
```

---

```
  _listenToDB = () => {
    database()
      .ref('users')
      .on('child_added', snapshot => {
        const key = snapshot.key;
        const value = snapshot.val();
        this.props._actAddUser({'key': key, 'value': value});
      });
```

---

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(App);

export const app = new App();
```

When function `_listenToDB` runs in `App`, it runs fine and the redux action creator `this.props._actAddUser(` is dispatched OK.....however when that same function is called from `Search`, it errors at the line `this.props._actAddUser(` because `this.props` is `undefined`.  In a perfect world, `this.props` *should* contain the Redux object that holds the action creator `_actAddUser`

Answer (score 0):

Decided to make it easy for myself and just moved function `_listenToDB` to a seperate `helperFunctions.js` file.
Thought it was only possible to access Redux from inside a Class/Component (using MapDispatchToProps) .....however then learned can use:

```
import { store } from '/path/to/createdStore';
store.dispatch(_actAddUser({'key': key, 'value': value}));
```